Deduce 3D position and angle from 3 2D joysticks
I have 3 joysticks arranged in a triangle facing outwards in the same plane. Each joystick can move in a set arc in 2 directions.
Each joystick looks like this:

The joysticks are arranged as follows (the green objects are the joysticks):

The result is a mushroom-shaped controller for manipulating 3D CAD programs:

If I raise the whole "mushroom" all 3 joysticks will have their Y axis to max
If I rotate the mushroom to the right all 3 joystick will have their X axis to max
If I tilt the mushroom to the left the bottom left joystick will have its Y axis to min, middle to neutral and right to max
Given the X and Y value of each joystick I want to calculate what to send the computer which is going to be X, Y, Z (for the respective movement of the mushroom) and RX, RY and RZ (for the respective angle of the mushroom)

In order to avoid ambiguities, it would be good to provide a graphical description. In particular : I don't understand the meaning of (Rx,Ry,Rz) in your animation ? Do you want to move an object which is in position (X,Y,Z) in the direction (Rx,Ry,Rz) ? A suggestion : give a "downgraded" (but easier to understand) description of 2 joysticks achieving the movement of a point in a plane instead of 3 joysticks in the space.

I added pictures and re-structured the question, is that any better?

Nice figures (Blender made ?). So your joysticks are in "rest positiion" in a same plane (P) orthogonal to the faces of an equilateral triangle ;  and the axis of the mushroow is orthogonal to plane (P). But you haven't still not said which information you want to obtain (via spherical geometry), in particular what is (X,Y,Z) with respect to (Rx,Ry,Rz)?
